# Selenium + Python Allow Firefox Notifications

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

there is such a question how to implement so that Selenium resolves in that case 
notifications like this photo
https://prod-cdn.sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2017-10-18-05-45-38-20e1d7.png

it is desirable that he press himself I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Following Code :**

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('permissions.default.desktop-notification', 1)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are a couple more questions.

Comment: @Kota : Does the answer helped you

Comment: Yes, I still asked one question above in this topic

Comment: can create a new topic for this?

Comment: @Kota : Can you please  explain your other question in details and if the notification issue is handled could you please accept the answer

Comment: @Kota : Yes for other question it will be great if you post another question

Comment: @Kota : by creating a new topic  you will separate two different problem ..which will helps other in future to take help of your question and provided answer

Comment: here is a link to topic 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445675/pythonselenium-edited-the-code-but-it-does-not-work-now