# Python+Selenium Edited the code but it does not work now

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

what I wanted to do to make it perform some actions but for some reason now the code does not work (
and still have a couple of questions
1) how to do when the browser is closed, it cleaned all the data
2) how to make the user agent to be taken from the txt file

I will be very grateful if you bring any example))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
import requests
import threading
import time

i = 0

mainThread = None
toURL = ""
toProxy = []
toChat = ""
toPause = 0
toScreen = 0
toThreads = 10
threads = []

def run2(proxyList):
    global status_now, toURL, toPause, toScreen
    if toURL.startswith("http://") or toURL.startswith("https://"):
        pass
    else:
        toURL = "http://" + toURL
    for proxy in proxyList:
        print("Proxy: " + proxy)
        proxyIP = proxy.split(":")[0]
        proxyPort = int(proxy.split(":")[1])
        getScreenshot(url = toURL, proxyIP = proxyIP, proxyPort = proxyPort, pause = toPause, toScreen = toScreen)

def run():
    global status_now, toURL, toPause, toProxy, toScreen, toThreads, threads
    def divide(lst,n):
        return [lst[i::n] for i in range(n)]
    proxies = divide(toProxy, toThreads)
    for proxyList in proxies:
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target = run2, args = (proxyList,)).start())

def getScreenshot(url, proxyIP = None, proxyPort = None, pause = 15, toScreen = False):
    global i
    opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    opts.add_argument("--headless")
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('permissions.default.desktop-notification', 1) #here added a code
    if proxyIP != None:
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", proxyIP)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", proxyPort)
        profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; PLUS Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.98 Mobile Safari/537.36")
    profile.update_preferences()
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_options=opts)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Не удалось инициализировать браузер")
        return
    driver.implicitly_wait(pause) # seconds
    print("Жду загрузки. " + str(pause) + " сек.")
    try:
        driver.get(url)  #here added a code
        elemen = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='y-button y-button_theme_base y-button_size_l y-button_type_link lpc-button']").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        elemen = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary']").click()
    except Exception as e:  #finished writing here
        print("Ошибка открытия страницы. ")
        try:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
        except Exception as e:
            return
        finally:
            return
    time.sleep(pause)
    try:
        driver.close()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    try:
        driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    i = i + 1
    print("Сделано. Всего:" + str(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainThread = None
    toURL = input("Введите ссылку: ")
    toPause = int(input("Введите сколько секунд ждать: "))
    toThreads = int(input("Сколько потоков (10 - оптимально): "))
    prox = [line.replace("\r","").strip('\n') for line in open('proxy.txt')]
    errorsProxy = 0
    for each in prox:
        x = each
        x = x.replace("1", "N").replace("2", "N").replace("3", "N")
        x = x.replace("4", "N").replace("5", "N").replace("6", "N")
        x = x.replace("7", "N").replace("8", "N").replace("9", "N")
        x = x.replace("0", "N").replace("NN", "N").replace("NN", "N").replace("NN", "N")
        if x == "N.N.N.N:N" and each != "N.N.N.N:N":
            toProxy.append(each)
        else:
            errorsProxy = errorsProxy + 1
    print("Загружено прокси: " + str(len(toProxy)) +". Ошибки в прокси: "+ str(errorsProxy))
    run()
```

Comment: What do you mean by this - "how to do when the browser is closed, it cleaned all the data "

Comment: these are translation errors

Comment: How to do it before closing the browser so that it clears the data

Comment: @PritamMaske Maske data like Cookies and Cash and so on

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and ["How much research effort is expected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.